# How does WordPress load themes? It doesn't see mine (symlinked)

Tags: themes

I'm storing my theme in Dropbox, normally i just create a symlink in: wp-content/themes to the directory in Dropbox and everything is fine.

It works well on my PC (XAMPP), it works well on Mac (MAMP), the problem is - I really needed to use XAMPP on Mac as well (MAMP uses much older MySQL).

And here's the deal - everything is fine, WordPress got installed, sql got imported and then after creating a symlink I can't see my theme on `http://localhost/mytheme/wp-admin/themes.php` page. There are all the basic themes but not mine. The symlink is a-okay. It points to the right place. I've tried setting chmods on it:

```
chmod 777 /Applications/.../SomeTheme
find /Applications/.../SomeTheme/ -type f | xargs -I {} chmod 644 {}
find /Applications/.../SomeTheme/ -type d | xargs -I {} chmod 755 {}
```

With no luck. How does WP load themes from /themes directory? What can I do in order to detect mine? I'm pretty much sure it's an issue with file permissions, because XAMPP has many problems with in on OSX (works fine on MAMP as I said). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a web server setting. If you use Apache, try to enable **FollowSymLinks**.